# Correlation between binary and categorical variables

Tags: correlation, nonlinear-regression, binary-data

what kind of correlation should I use in the case of having one dependent binary variable (has been to the doctor in the past few months) and one independent categorical variable, i.e, education?

Comment: What do you want to do, what questions do you want the data to answer?  You could try logistic regression with  "been to doctor" as response, education as covariate.